# Convert Calendar to String

Tags: java, string, date, calendar

I want to convert Calendar output to String. The following is my code

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Time is "+cal.getTime());
String str=cal.getTime();   //This is how I want to store the output, but this is wrong.
```

Here the output of the getTime() method is of 'Date' type, so getting error.
Is there any way to typecast or any solution?

Comment: `String str = cal.getTime().toString()`

Answer (score -1):

Please refer:

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance(); 
System.out.println("Time is "+cal.getTime()); 
String str=cal.toString();
System.out.println("Time is "+str);
```